# Removing integrated video card drivers broke other hardware?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, drivers

I just purchased and installed an XFX ATI Radeon HD 4650 video card. The installation instructions said to remove the old video card drivers before installing the new driver. I did both things, but now every time I start my computer, the Found New Hardware wizard pops up for the following three devices:

1. PCI Device
2. SM Bus Controller
3. Other PCI Bridge Device

Furthermore, my LAN port no longer functions. The cable's connected, and the light on the port comes on, but the computer can't find any servers when I attempt to connect with it. The modem and router are working, and obviously I'm able to use the other computer here to post this.

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you uninstalled your chip set drivers. You can reacquire this at the manufactures website of the motherboard typically.

If you want to selectively install parts of the chip set driver pack you can often unzip it with 7zip and install the ones you want.

Comment: Sounds like that's exactly what the problem is here. The chipset drivers may be on a CD you received with the computer (or motherboard if you built it yourself)

Comment: This fixed my internet, and of the three "new" devices, only the PCI device is still coming up. Thanks, guys!